# Mapping on a sending props ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

This is the data

```
const people = [
    {
      img: 11,
      name: "Ahmed",
      job: "developer",
    },
    {
      img: 13,
      name: "Kazim",
      job: "Engineer",
    },
]
```

I'm trying to map these properties that I'm sending separately.

```
<Person person={people[0]} />
<Person person={people[1]}/>
<Person person={people[2]} />
```

I tried this

```
{people.map((i) => (
  <Person person={people[i]} />
))}
```

But it gives this error

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'img' of 'props.person' as it is undefined.
```

I tried sending it along with the key as well, but it still gives the same error.

I tried this as well

```
 people.map((person,i) => {
      return (
        <Person
          key={i}
          img={person[i].img}
          name={person[i].name}
          job={person[i].job} 
        />
     );
  );
```

But it gives this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined
```

Comment: `{people.map((i) => (
  <Person person={i} />
))}`

Comment: @hev1 Thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the callback for `map` is the element itself, not the index.

```
{people.map((i) => (
  <Person person={i} />
))}
```

Answer (score 3):

it should be person in your second map

```
 people.map((person,i) => {
      return (
        <Person
          key={i}
          img={person.img}
          name={person.name}
          job={person.job} 
        />
     );
  );
```